# Descoprimir zip demasiado lento con java

Tags: java

```
 public static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDir) throws IOException{

      try(ZipFile file = new ZipFile(zipFilePath))
        {

            FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
            //Get file entries
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();

            //We will unzip files in this folder
            String uncompressedDirectory = destDir;
            Files.createDirectory(fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedDirectory));

            //Iterate over entries
            while (entries.hasMoreElements())
            {
                ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                //If directory then create a new directory in uncompressed folder
                if (entry.isDirectory())
                {
                    int h=entry.getName().indexOf('/');
                    String e=entry.getName().substring(h);
                    System.out.println("Creating Directory:" + uncompressedDirectory + e);
                    Files.createDirectories(fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedDirectory + e));
                }
                //Else create the file
                else
                {
                    InputStream is = file.getInputStream(entry);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    int h=entry.getName().indexOf('/');
                    String e=entry.getName().substring(h);
                    String uncompressedFileName = uncompressedDirectory + e;
                    Path uncompressedFilePath = fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedFileName);
                    Files.createFile(uncompressedFilePath);
                    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(uncompressedFileName);
                    while (bis.available() > 0)
                    {
                        fileOutput.write(bis.read());
                    }
                    fileOutput.close();
                    System.out.println("Written :" + entry.getName());
                }
            }
            file.close();
            File f = new File(zipFilePath);
            f.delete();
            log.info("Se ha realizado la descompresion de la nueva version");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Me gustaría si hay alguna parte del código que se pueda cambiar para descomprimir zips de forma más rápida. El problema es que tengo que descomprimir zips de mas de 20 MB y tardan cada uno como 5 o 6 minutos.

Comment: ¿No tendrá que ver más la forma en que se hizo la compresión o los tipos de archivos que se agregan en el zip?

Comment: son los .jar lo que tarda, las clase y demás lo hace en un segundo

Comment: Lo que sucede es que los jar ya están "comprimidos", ya que al ser clases de java compiladas se utiliza un algoritmo parecido a los archivos zip para empaquetarlos y que ocupen menos espacio en donde se vayan a utilizar. De tal forma que cuando tu los comprimes le estas agregando una segunda compresión.